# API service works every second request

Tags: java, android, mysql, hibernate

I have problem with  jax-rs REST service.

Service does not operate properly. Every  second request service throw me exception:

```
HTTP Status 500 - could not execute query

type Exception report

message could not execute query

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:74)
    org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2147)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2028)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2023)
    org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:95)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1569)
    org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283)
    com.fit.utilities.BaseDAO.getAll_fetchEager(BaseDAO.java:62)
    com.fit.utilities.BaseDAO.getAll(BaseDAO.java:37)
    com.fit.servis.Korisnik_servis.PronadjiPrijatelje(Korisnik_servis.java:174)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1483)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1414)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1363)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1353)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:414)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.Connection was implicitly closed by the driver.
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:929)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1204)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1191)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4276)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4242)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:497)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:415)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:139)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1560)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:661)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:224)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2144)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2028)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2023)
    org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:95)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1569)
    org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283)
    com.fit.utilities.BaseDAO.getAll_fetchEager(BaseDAO.java:62)
    com.fit.utilities.BaseDAO.getAll(BaseDAO.java:37)
    com.fit.servis.Korisnik_servis.PronadjiPrijatelje(Korisnik_servis.java:174)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1483)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1414)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1363)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1353)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:414)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 22.477.953 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 22.478.000 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1122)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3317)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1941)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2114)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2696)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2105)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2264)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1668)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:662)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:224)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2144)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2028)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2023)
    org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:95)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1569)
    org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283)
    com.fit.utilities.BaseDAO.getAll_fetchEager(BaseDAO.java:62)
    com.fit.utilities.BaseDAO.getAll(BaseDAO.java:37)
    com.fit.servis.Korisnik_servis.Login(Korisnik_servis.java:32)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1483)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1414)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1363)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1353)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:414)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3298)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1941)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2114)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2696)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2105)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2264)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1668)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:662)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:224)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2144)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2028)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2023)
    org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:95)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1569)
    org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283)
    com.fit.utilities.BaseDAO.getAll_fetchEager(BaseDAO.java:62)
    com.fit.utilities.BaseDAO.getAll(BaseDAO.java:37)
    com.fit.servis.Korisnik_servis.Login(Korisnik_servis.java:32)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1483)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1414)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1363)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1353)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:414)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.32 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.32
```

Service retrieve  JSON..I think that the problem is due to the size byte string.

**Example of successful response:**

```
[{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "haris",
    "surname": null,
    "gender": null,
    "age": null,
    "birthdate": null,
    "password": "1234",
    "username": "haris",
    "isOnline": null,
    "picture": "YORp0a9HAkEbrPYu2RcNwB4ExIMdvoD5/3uBgoz1"
}]
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with REST or the wrong tagging of JAX-WS. This is a data layer issue. You need to work on the timeout setting of MySQL to keep the connection alive longer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your mysql datasource configuration. Try to add this two parameters to the datasource definition:

```
 testOnBorrow="true" validationQuery="select 1"
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is server side problem. Its clearly visible your class **BaseDAO** executing a method **getAll_fetchEager** in this method you are making some criteria query which fails due to some reason. I am sure if you correct your criteria query problem will resolve. Try to find out connection properties are properly set and you are able to connect your database.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is in the stack trace.

> The last packet successfully received from the server was 22.477.953 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 22.478.000 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.

The connection to your `mysql` isn't being kept open, and isn't set to auto reconnect.